# Customzing Flask-Admin based on instance

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'd like to add or remove some *form_extra_fields* based on the **instance** that will be displayed. The documentation is extensive around customizing the form for every member of the class but I'm having problems finding a hook where I can access the instance itself.